# How to refer a property in a value of another property in the same Javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, object, this

In a Gulp.js file (but it can be any Javascript file) I set the paths in a Javascript object:

```
var paths = {
    devDir : 'builds/development/',
    devDirGlobs : this.devDir+'*.html'              
}
```

Now, as you can see, I'm trying to recall the property "**devDir**" in the value of the property "**devDirGlobs**", as "**this.devDir**".

It doesn't work, but also it doesn't give to me any error?

Any hint?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can’t do that. Sorry. You’ll have to assign to the other property separately, or put the value of `devDir` in a variable beforehand.

Comment: It won't work but this may point you in the right direction - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations

Comment: thanks minitech I've used your solution, equivalent to dan-prince solution! And thanks to dontfeedthecode for pointing me out the full explanation, as Yoshi right mark of duplicate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to access the properties of the object before the object has been declared.

However, you could construct the object with dot syntax rather than as a literal.

```
var paths = {}
paths.devDir = 'builds/development/';
paths.devDirGlobs = paths.devDir + '*.html';
```

Or move common values into a shared config object.

```
var config = {
  dir: 'builds/development'
};

var paths = {    
  devDir : config.dir,
  devDirGlobs : config.dir + '*.html'              
};
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful if I need to make more than one property depends on another property and avoids the natural "function solution"!